# Flutter decoding of large json sometimes gives errors while parsing

Tags: json, flutter, dio

Im using dio to retrieve large json data from my Laravel backend, the problem is that, sometimes it works perfectly and it gets parsed correctly, and sometimes it returns:

> FormatException: Unexpected character

Here is how im using dio:

```
class CartRepository {
  final dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: API.apiURL,
    connectTimeout: 120 * 1000,
    receiveTimeout: 120 * 1000,
  ));

  Future<void> initializeToken() async {
    final token = await Storage.getToken();

    dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'Application/json';
    dio.options.headers['Accept'] = 'Application/json';
    dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = token;
  }

  Future<Cart?> getCartProducts({required String storeUUID}) async {
    await initializeToken();

    try {
      final Response<String> response = await dio.get(API.apiURL + 'cart/$storeUUID');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final products = Cart.fromMap(jsonDecode(response.data!)); // <<<<<<<<

        return products;
      }
    } on DioError catch (exception) {
      if (exception.type == DioErrorType.response) {
        if (exception.response!.statusCode == 401) {
          throw UnauthorizedException();
        } else {
          throw ServerErrorException();
        }
      }

      log(exception.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the error:

> [log] DioError [DioErrorType.other]: FormatException: Unexpected
> character (at character 30379)
> ...Dv0gII9i2AK.jpg",**"image_0_url:null**,"image_1_url":"product_images/oKoNzu...

Notice that "image_0_url is missing the end quote.
The issue is that this same exact endpoint works well sometimes and doesnt work sometimes, and also, it never failed on postman, it always returns the correct json.

I have tested the returned json many times with online validated, also when i use postman to retrieve the exact same json data, it gets parsed correctly with never any issues.

PS: Please do comment on my implementation of the whole functionality if you notice a better way to do it

Comment: Try using regular `package:http` and see if you can reproduce the issue there. Also, this line makes no sense `dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'Application/json';` You are telling the server that your body contains JSON, but you are doing a `GET` which has no body.

Answer (score 2):

`response.data` is already decoded by dio.

> The default value is `json`, dio will parse response string to json object automatically when the content-type of response is 'application/json'.

Comment: Yes i have been editing the DIO implementation and i was using ResponseType.plain at some point set everything to use String, however this still doesnt solve the issue i have

Answer (score 0):

There will be cases where your server might misbehave. It's always advised to handle null cases. In your model Model(url: json["json_url"]?? "https://a_fallback_imahlge.jpg")

Comment: The model does handle null values, i noticed the issue only when i add too many items to the cart which increases the size of json data to 30kb+, also, in the example i provided, there seems to be a missing quote rather than a an issue with handling null values dont you think ?

Comment: Now that you've drawn my attention to it, yes. The issue could be with the data. I experienced this issue once where someone erroneously uploaded integers to a double field. The json displayed both in the same manner and we were losing our heads